How to connect to a Docker Java socket from an Android Emulated Application on localhost
I have the following docker container and I am trying to connect to it from Android Studio emulated phone. On the phone logcat I get the error:
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 1234) from /:: (port 49626): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
This is the docker container info:
{
    "Id": "c23d4bb8709ef13aaa558821ac4cf5aacd1cbff3e0b8a8b1c85a36fa7cf4ae66",
    "Created": "2024-06-04T18:32:22.478302527Z",
    "Path": "/__cacert_entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "java",
        "-jar",
        "FCMS.jar"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 20822,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2024-06-04T18:32:23.013000218Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:7fdc162db088d15b898bb14b89d2117752281368e2d7fdbe15ec355e88d9b392",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c23d4bb8709ef13aaa558821ac4cf5aacd1cbff3e0b8a8b1c85a36fa7cf4ae66/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c23d4bb8709ef13aaa558821ac4cf5aacd1cbff3e0b8a8b1c85a36fa7cf4ae66/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c23d4bb8709ef13aaa558821ac4cf5aacd1cbff3e0b8a8b1c85a36fa7cf4ae66/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/c23d4bb8709ef13aaa558821ac4cf5aacd1cbff3e0b8a8b1c85a36fa7cf4ae66/c23d4bb8709ef13aaa558821ac4cf5aacd1cbff3e0b8a8b1c85a36fa7cf4ae66-json.log",
    "Name": "/fcms",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "1234/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "1234"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": true,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "host",
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": [],
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware",
            "/sys/devices/virtual/powercap"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebc9292164c7208cb422cbad2f6f5317a852153ebaf07c95d0fded94cd25a99b-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/r7qce143p01wl85fgqb12r7b9/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/tcx71kyqp9oeuejufqbdhxbvb/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7be6s2pfdp2hb1rk0htdeatg3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0cjzrmhvj40ntmhv5hmce00xi/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/59f1b26cc58acb6634b370f2a0287bd2b3c6fdfc578ee5db0aeb1a226daf9233/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6c8d4669466a22f164f52118b0e7b8b0e74774349bd8bb83fee7ce14cab8451f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/17a3a681b844eee48f07e897d4ad93f088132a9c6e0da24ffaba482cd280d017/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/613b7915c9722c24693423fabad0ffcab66426536fcee2638fa930dc614c5e8b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/117e567bfe13aeb900fd225ff0ef0f3ca3b213c5ba6af9cce4ed4cad3b629b3c/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebc9292164c7208cb422cbad2f6f5317a852153ebaf07c95d0fded94cd25a99b/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebc9292164c7208cb422cbad2f6f5317a852153ebaf07c95d0fded94cd25a99b/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebc9292164c7208cb422cbad2f6f5317a852153ebaf07c95d0fded94cd25a99b/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "fcms",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "user",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "1234/tcp": {},
            "1234/udp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk",
            "LANG=en_US.UTF-8",
            "LANGUAGE=en_US:en",
            "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8",
            "JAVA_VERSION=jdk-17.0.11+9"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "java",
            "-jar",
            "FCMS.jar"
        ],
        "Image": "fcms",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/runtime",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/__cacert_entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
            "org.opencontainers.image.version": "22.04"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "544a80f6495c29a42bbd4327c72ac1e00a1be9f1700d1d3217e9e0a7373823a8",
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/544a80f6495c",
        "Ports": {
            "1234/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "1234"
                }
            ],
            "1234/udp": null
        },
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "703ecf9bfd7b8cfa7f0df6cdf6eb93a098e1eae4336a534aa04ed8be8d836ba1",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "NetworkID": "f97b1b820cbc85e8efd37a818a0c5dbaaeb9cd823bec3407371cf041b2ba35a4",
                "EndpointID": "703ecf9bfd7b8cfa7f0df6cdf6eb93a098e1eae4336a534aa04ed8be8d836ba1",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "DriverOpts": null,
                "DNSNames": null
            }
        }
    }
}

I have also checked netstat and it appears as listening:
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
TCP    0.0.0.0:135            DESKTOP-670L2MO:0      LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            DESKTOP-670L2MO:0      LISTENING
TCP    0.0.0.0:1234           DESKTOP-670L2MO:0      LISTENING

This is the Java Code of the Docker application:
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

while (true) {
    try {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Waiting");
        ConnectionTCP connectionTCP = new ConnectionTCP(serverSocket.accept());
        new Client(connectionTCP);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Connection Accepted");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

Android App Code:
private static String HOSTNAME = "localhost";
private static int PORT = 1234;

try {
    this.socket = new Socket(HOSTNAME, PORT);
    Logging.logd(this.getClass().getName(), "Creating the ConnectionTCP object");
    this.reader = createReader(socket);
    this.writer = createWriter(socket);
    ....
}

Dockerfile:
FROM maven:3.9.7-eclipse-temurin-17 AS build
COPY . ./build/
WORKDIR ./build/

RUN mvn clean package

FROM eclipse-temurin:17 as runtime

RUN useradd user

WORKDIR /runtime

RUN chown user /runtime

COPY --from=build /build/target/FCMS-jar-with-dependencies.jar ./FCMS.jar

EXPOSE 1234/TCP
EXPOSE 1234/UDP

USER user

CMD ["java","-jar","FCMS.jar"]

build and run bash:
echo "building docker image"

docker buildx build -t fcms ..\.

echo "running docker"

docker remove --force fcms

docker run --rm --name fcms -p 0.0.0.0:1234:1234 --hostname fcms  fcms

echo _____________
echo SUCCESS
echo _____________
pause

If I am hosting it on a totally different linux machine(a Raspberry PI) it works with no issues(I am running directly the .jar file on the Raspberry Pi). The port is 1234.
I have added the -p 1234:1234 to the run command but the same issue, I tried to ping the docker container via normal ping and I get timeout. In the Dockerfile I have also exposed the port.
What I have observed is that if I try to http using web browser to the localhost:1234 it is connecting to my service. Of course it is not the correct packets sent because the server is not html but still


The IP address of the docker container is not 127.0.0.1 from outside it.

@user207421 but what it is, I have also tried 172.17.0.4 and it is not working.
